# Remove characters in String that appear after specific character

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script, I'm attempting to remove all characters from a string that appear after a specific character.

When I perform Logger.log(data) I get this:

```
[17-12-14 19:31:55:251 GMT] 
[17-12-14 19:31:55:252 GMT] ID
[17-12-14 19:31:55:253 GMT] 11111||q467jeX
[17-12-14 19:31:55:254 GMT] undefined
[17-12-14 19:31:55:255 GMT] 
[17-12-14 19:31:55:256 GMT] ID
[17-12-14 19:31:55:257 GMT] undefined
[17-12-14 19:31:55:258 GMT] 22222||K6OmenP
[17-12-14 19:31:55:259 GMT]
```

I would like to remove all characters that come after "|", so that "data" looks like:

```
[17-12-14 19:31:55:251 GMT] 
[17-12-14 19:31:55:252 GMT] ID
[17-12-14 19:31:55:253 GMT] 11111
[17-12-14 19:31:55:254 GMT] undefined
[17-12-14 19:31:55:255 GMT] 
[17-12-14 19:31:55:256 GMT] ID
[17-12-14 19:31:55:257 GMT] undefined
[17-12-14 19:31:55:258 GMT] 22222
[17-12-14 19:31:55:259 GMT]
```

I've tried using .split, .map and .subString methods, but I must be doing something wrong. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: As per the definition of javascript tag: "`JavaScript (not to be confused with Java) is a high-level, dynamic, multi-paradigm, weakly-typed language used for both client-side and server-side scripting. Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its various dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript and Google-Apps-Script)`"

Comment: @JohanP thanks Johan. I will omit the javascript tag for google script questions in future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JavaScript String split() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```
var text = "22222||K6OmenP";
var data = text.split("|")[0];
Logger.log(data);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much! As the variable "data" held multiple objects, I iterated through each one before using your code:

    for (j = 1; j< data.length; j++){
      var data = data.split("|")[0];
    }

Answer (score 1):

.indexOf is the method you are looking for. Do a x.substring(0,x.indexOf('|'));

Answer (score 0):

If this is a string in Javascript (the question is tagged javascript) you should be able to achieve your wanted result with a [simple regex](https://regex101.com/r/RdssVA/1):

```
const subject = `[17-12-14 19:31:55:251 GMT] 
[17-12-14 19:31:55:252 GMT] ID
[17-12-14 19:31:55:253 GMT] 11111||q467jeX
[17-12-14 19:31:55:254 GMT] undefined
[17-12-14 19:31:55:255 GMT] 
[17-12-14 19:31:55:256 GMT] ID
[17-12-14 19:31:55:257 GMT] undefined
[17-12-14 19:31:55:258 GMT] 22222||K6OmenP
[17-12-14 19:31:55:259 GMT]
`;

const result = subject.replace(/(\|.*)$/gm, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing `console.log(str)` or `Logger.log(str)`

So try just replacing that `str` with `String(str).subString(0, String(str).indexOf('|'))`

Thanks.